# How to get array of polygons which are intersects by a Linestring in PostGIS

Tags: polygon, postgis

I have two tables named `polygon` & `paths` which contains polygons data and paths(line string) respectively. I am trying to build a query in which I will pass lineString data and on the basis of that, I want to fetch all the polygons which that lineString intersects.

I am quite new to this Please suggest some approach by the help of that I can be able to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is very general. But if you want to get the polygons that intersects with the line then the query in postgis would be something like this

```
SELECT p.* FROM polygon_table AS p, line_table as l
WHERE
st_intersects(p.geom, l.geom)
```

geom are the columns representing the geometry column, and make sure that both tables have same SRID.